# how to change the order of a discrete x scale in ggplot with unbalenced data (NA on the x-axis)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to do a faceted ggplot2 plot of error bars, but failing. Data is much like this...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df0 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = ifelse(Sepal.Length > mean(Sepal.Length), 
         yes = "long", no = "short")) %>%
  group_by(Species, long_sepal) %>%
  mutate(petal_rank = order(Petal.Width)) %>%
  filter(petal_rank <= 5) %>%
  mutate(petal_rank = factor(petal_rank))

> df0
# Source: local data frame [30 x 7]
# Groups: Species, long_sepal [6]
# 
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species long_sepal petal_rank
#           (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)  (fctr)      (chr)      (int)
# 1           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       long          1
# 2           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa      short          1
# 3           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa      short          2
# 4           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa      short          3
# 5           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa      short          4
# 6           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa       long          3
# 7           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa       long          4
# 8           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa       long          2
# 9           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa       long          5
# 10          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa      short          5
# ..          ...         ...          ...         ...     ...        ...        ...
```

I could use the `scale_x_discrete` function to order the discrete axis as I require (i.e. `short` first, uncomment in the plot code below). However, my data has some groups where there is no classification for the variable on the x-axis, so more like:

```
df0 <- df0 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = ifelse(Species != "virginica", yes = long_sepal, no = NA),
         long_sepal = factor(long_sepal))
```

The plot code gives either gives an `NA` on the x-axis, which I want to avoid...

```
ggplot(data = df0, 
       aes(x = long_sepal, y = Petal.Width, group = factor(petal_rank),
           ymin = Petal.Width-0.05, 
           ymax = Petal.Width+0.05)) + 
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free") # + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("short", "long"))
```

[image]

... or an error message when I uncomment the `scale_x_discrete` function;

```
Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is there anyway to do the plot with a specified order of the discrete values and without an `NA` label in the facet with no categorisation for the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you map `x` to a factored version of `long_sepal`, you can change the order, but that won't get rid of the `NA`; you'll need the `scale_x_discrete` too. You need to set `breaks`, though, not `limits`:

```
ggplot(data = df0, 
       aes(x = factor(long_sepal, levels = c('short', 'long')), 
           y = Petal.Width, group = factor(petal_rank),
           ymin = Petal.Width-0.05, 
           ymax = Petal.Width+0.05)) + 
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("short", "long"))
```

[image: plot with correct x labels]

Note the `factor` method screws up the main x label, but you'll probably want to set that with `xlab` or whatnot, anyway. Also, you lose the `NA` vertical gridline, if that's a concern.